# Map request into aws service without lambdas and using AWS service proxy integration on Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis, serverless-framework, serverless

So i've got a scenario that i want to use an endpoint and map the provided requests directly into Kinesis stream.

I was able to do that manually in the aws console.
[image]

But is there a way to do change the integration to aws service using serverless or serverless plugin?

I tried to find a way to deploy an endpoint that communicates directly with an aws service, without lambdas, and could not find it.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same.  Did you find out if it's possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, the only way i got it working is to do it manually on the console, this question didn't got much attention so i assume that is not a common thing :/

Comment: @LG not sure if you still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while but recently i noticed that there's a plugin now that helps setup this exact configuration, https://github.com/horike37/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy

```
custom:
  apiGatewayServiceProxies:
    - kinesis:
        path: /kinesis
        method: post
        streamName: { Ref: 'YourStream' }
        cors:
          origin: '*'
          headers:
            - Content-Type
            - X-Amz-Date
            - Authorization
            - X-Api-Key
            - X-Amz-Security-Token
            - X-Amz-User-Agent
          allowCredentials: false
```

Hope this helps others that are still having this problem