# mapping API Gateway websockets directly to a kinesis stream in serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, amazon-kinesis

I have a kinesis stream:

```
  resources:
    Resources:
      KinesisStream:
        Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
        Properties:
          Name: "websockets-stream"
          ShardCount: 1
```

and a function that can be triggered either by a message from a websocket connection or the kinesis stream:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - websocket: $default
      - stream:
          type: kinesis
          arn: .....
```

Is there a way to define API Gateway websocket endpoint and link it directly to kinesis stream without an intermediary lambda? I want my lambdas listen to kinsesis streams and my kinsesis streams fed data directly from AWS sources which i want defined in serverless.yml outside of lambda definitions.

Comment: unless i understood wrong its similar to a question i had a while ago but this time with websocket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409515/map-request-into-aws-service-without-lambdas-and-using-aws-service-proxy-integra 
but you might be able to get things working with the serverless-apigateway-service-proxy pluging